# Razor Pages On Server Validation returning for without some fields

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm having an issue with a server side validation with Razor Pages (ASP.Net Core 2.0)

I have a page that creates a record

http://localhost:56876/Entries/Create?employeeID=112345

my code behind file for the OnGet looks like:

```
      [BindProperty]
        public EntryLog EntryLog { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee{ get; set; }
        public string empID { get; set; }

  public IActionResult OnGet(string employeeID)
        {
        empID = employeeID;
// for Selects for lookup tables
        ViewData["ReasonId"] = new SelectList(_context.Reason, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["ReasonTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ReasonType, "Id", "Name");
            return Page();
        }
```

The code above works just fine and client validation works perfect but I have business logic validation that if the Entry Date is 90 between today's date and hired date that I should not let the entry to be saved.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
            {
    //Lookup current employeeID hiredDate. if is new employee do not continue.

                Employee  = await _context.Employee .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == EntryLog.EmployeeID);

//Server side validation
                var age = DateTime.Today.Day - Employee.HireDate.Day;
                if (age <= 90)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("NewEmp", "Emp is New Warning");
                    return Page();
                }

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return Page();
                }

                _context.EntryLog.Add(EntryLog);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
```

My server side validation works but the problem is that when I return Page();
The form gets refreshed and the two selects elements get empty out and the EmployeeID element gets empty out as well.

My guess is that the return Page() on OnPostAsync() is not calling the OnGet() method.

How can I keep the page as it is without loosing the info?

Comment: You don't have any model for your method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right the `return Page()` does not call `OnGet()` method. I´ll try to explain what is happening:

**Short Answer:**

When you receive the Post request (`OnPost()`) and `return Page()` the server just returns the response (html), it does not make a new Get Request so that `OnGet()` get called again.

The two selects elements are being cleant because they are set up in `OnGet()` through `ViewData` (that is temporary) not in `OnPost()`. My suggestion is that you set the "selects" again on `OnPost()` (extract to a method to make it easier).

**Long Answer:**

When you access your Page (Entries/Create) by typing or being redirected through a link, the browser request the page to the server using HTTP METHOD GET, which will invoke `OnGet` method. Afterwards, when you send your form (considering `method="POST"`) the request will be sent to the server and be caught by the `OnPost` method.

When you code `return Page()`, it is not sending back a response to browser saying "Hey, you have to make a GET request again (what would make `OnGet` be called again)", it is returning the end response (html) itself. That´s why `OnGet()` is not being called. What would make the `OnGet()` be called again would be `return RedirectToPage("./Entities/Create")`, but doing so you would lose your Model state (validation result).

The two selects elements are being cleant because they are set up in `OnGet()` through `ViewData` (that is temporary) not in `OnPost()`. My suggestion is that you set the "selects" again on `OnPost()` (extract to a method to make it easier).

Regards.

Comment: I could not get it to work loading the selectboxes onPost, anyone else?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `OnGet` from your `OnPost` method, i.e.:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return OnGet();
}
```

This works for me in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and preserves all validation errors.

Comment: Quick & simple answer and it works for me! thank you :)