# What happens after a return Page();

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `public ActionResult OnPostAddApplication` method which contains the following code

`if (!ModelState.IsValid){return Page();}` once i return the page my html select items lose their options. Initially i assumed that after calling `Page()` the get method would be invoked but it isn't. I'm wondering what happens after page is called, and how can i reload my select lists

This deletion of options occurs when i submit a form with validation errors

I've read up on the intro to razor pages

> When the submitted form has validation errors (that are passed to the server), theOnPostAsync handler method calls the Page helper method. Page returns an instance of PageResult. Returning Page is similar to how actions in controllers return View. PageResult is the default return type for a handler method. A handler method that returns void renders the page

This doesn't really tell my anything, or at least to me it isn't helping

Answer (score 0):

if the modelState is invalid you must return the checked model object to the page, to show it on Page().

OnPostAddApplication what object recive ? you must send it to Page(object).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnPostAddApplication(YourFormObject formParams){
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(formParams);
            }
}
```

Comment: Im a little confused here. So i have to send my form to this function, then return a page with my old form? ```return Page(form);```

Comment: ModelState.IsValid indicates if it was possible to bind the incoming values from the request to the model correctly and whether any explicitly specified validation rules were broken during the model binding process. If isValid is false, you send the Model because it got the error messages to show it in the user view.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading this post [Razor Pages On Server Validation returning for without some fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715684/razor-pages-on-server-validation-returning-for-without-some-fields)

I came up with this solution

```
 public ActionResult OnPostAddApplication()
        {
            PopulateTools();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid){return Page();}
```

I'm not exactly sure why repopulating the select items before returning the page if there is an error works. I think it has something to do with the form data being saved in ModelState, and if i send the select list info before the return, it gets added to the ModelState as well?